# How do I properly handle resources when emitting from a Roslyn workspace?

Tags: c#, embedded-resource, roslyn

I'm working on a project where we are compiling, emitting and running code using Roslyn. I've run into an issue where Roslyn does not embed resource files in the DLLs I emit using [`Compilation.Emit()`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Compilation/Compilation.cs,9f62285c857030a3).

I see there is an argument of type `IEnumerable<ResourceDescription>` which I think I need to use.

Unfortunately, I can't find any information on resources in [`Project`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/Solution/Project.cs,d40daa52fa32a6c4), so I'm not sure how to get the information I need.

Does Roslyn allow users to uncover any information about resource files? Or will I need to fall back to EnvDTE or using MSBuild manually? (If I need to use MSBuild, how do I support DNX projects?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this information bypasses the project system, and is instead passed directly from the MSBuild loader to the command line arguments.

[Source](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Desktop/Workspace/MSBuild/CSharp/CSharpProjectFileLoader.CSharpProjectFile.cs,64e7bee3103036bc)

Comment: Yeah the bottom line here is that it's not currently possible. I've opened an issue to discuss this: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7772